# How I can get the categories of an current product ordred hearchicaly in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am in single product page of the woocommerce plugin I would create a breadcrumb, so how I can get the categories of this product ordred hierarchical order ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the breadcrumb of a product, you can use the function `woocommerce_breadcrumb();`. I think you can save a lot of time using that function instead of creating one from zero.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'breadcrumb', 1 );
function bbloomer_custom_action() {
    echo woocommerce_breadcrumb();
}
```

This is how it looks in my theme. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjiIL.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the woocommerce breadcrumb dont work with all theme, and in my theme also, this is why I try to make my own breadcrumb and I found It ! I will share it . thanks again !.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this solution to make your custom breadcrumb of the current product in woocommerce single product page :

```
<?php
            $product_id = get_queried_object_id();
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );

            $number_of_terms   = count($terms);
            $breadcrumb        = array();  
            $breadcrumb_finish = false;
            $parent            = 0;

            while ( $breadcrumb_finish == false ) {
                  foreach ($terms as $term) {
                     if($term->parent == $parent)
                       {
                         $link_breadcrumb = "<span>".$term->name."</span>";
                         array_push($breadcrumb, $link_breadcrumb);
                         $parent = $term->term_id;
                       }
                  }
                  if(count($breadcrumb) == $number_of_terms)
                    $breadcrumb_finish = true; 
            }
          print_r($breadcrumb);
         ?>
```